# Trying to change background by updating state in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, background, styling

So I am writing an app which has several games on it. 
I want the user to be able to click a button and the game appears on the screen, and the background changes color.
I want to control this using state so that the background of the whole app changes, not just the game component.

With my code the way it is now, the state changes when the game is out, but the page does not update. Any advice?

this is how my state looks

```
state = {
  madLibsOut: false,
  ticTacOut: false,
  pigLatinOut: false,
  background: "green",
}
```

here is an example of my trying to change it. The state does change, and the game appears on the screen, but the background color does not update.

```
handleClickTicTacToe = () => {
  const out = this.state.ticTacOut
  const newColor = 'red'
  this.setState({ ticTacOut: true, background: newColor })
}
```

just in case it is useful, here is how I am setting the style:

```
appStyle={
  backgroundColor: this.state.background,
  height: "100vh",
  width: "100%",
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App" style={this.appStyle}>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you're setting your state as a **class variable** and it gets instantiated **once** and the value will **never** change.

Assuming you have **ES6** enabled. You should do something similar to what @Allessandro Messori said. 
But in his solution it isn't good to modify the property of an object and set the state.

When setting the state you should usually create a new object to set the state with. In this case your style object should be a new object.

```
state = {
  madLibsOut: false,
  ticTacOut: false,
  pigLatinOut: false,
  appStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "green",
    height: "100vh",
    width: "100%",
  } 
}


handleClickTicTacToe = () => {
  const out = this.state.ticTacOut
  // Use Object.assign(this.state.appStyle, { backgroundColor: 'red' }); if no ES6 enabled
  const newStyle = { ...this.state.appStyle, backgroundColor: 'red' }; 
  this.setState({ ticTacOut: true, appStyle: newStyle })
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App" style={this.state.appStyle}>
```

Another option is to create a function that returns your style which will always update based on your state. Assuming your original code you can update your code to this.

```
getAppStyle = () => {
  return {
    backgroundColor: this.state.background,
    height: "100vh",
    width: "100%",
  };
}

render() {
  const style = this.getAppStyle();
  return (
    <div className="App" style={style}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make appStyle a function that returns the style object based on your state.

```
appStyle = () => {
    return {
        backgroundColor:this.state.backgroundColor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should out all the appStyle object inside your component state.

Something like this should work:

```
  state = {
     madLibsOut: false,
     ticTacOut: false,
     pigLatinOut: false,
     appStyle:{
     backgroundColor: "green",
     height: "100vh",
     width: "100%",
    }
 }


  handleClickTicTacToe = () => {
    const out = this.state.ticTacOut
    let appStyle = this.state.appStyle
    appStyle.backgroundColor = 'red'
    this.setState({ticTacOut: true, appStyle:appStyle})
 }

  render() {
   return (
      <div className="App" style={this.state.appStyle}>
```

Comment: "I made those changes, and got and error that says
'TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'backgroundColor' of object '#<Object>"

it seems to be mad about the line that says
    appStyle.backgroundColor = 'red'

Comment: try using declaring appStyle with let instead of const